# Deleting an element in a vector by value

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, stl, polymorphism

How can I retrieve an object from the Flight to be compared to the input (flightNumber) in the main? How do I declare the attributes type in the main?

When I compile, a error message is displayed: `invalid conversion of 'int' to '*Flight*'` at `agent1.delete(flightNumber);`.

```
class Flight
{
    int FlightNumber 
};

class TravelAgent
{
    vector <Flight *> flightList;
};

void Agent::delete(Flight *obj)
{
    vector<Flight*>::iterator ptr;
    for(ptr=flightList.begin();ptr!=flightList.end();ptr++)
    {
        if((*Ptr)==obj)
        {
            flightList.erase(ptr);
            break;
        }
    }
    if ((ptr) == flightList.end())
    {
        cout<<"Flight not found"<<endl;
    }
}

int main
{
      Agent agent1;
      int flightNumber;
      cout<<"Enter the number of the flight: "<<flush;
      in>>flightNumber;
      agent1.delete(flightNumber); 
}
```

Comment: where has `fPtr` of the second if condition been declared before? Also, the error is in which line?

Comment: `flightNumber` is an int and you are trying to pass it to your `Agent::delete` method which accepts one `Flight*` parameter NOT an int.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi yes I am aware of that. So, could there be any possible solution to my question or any similar reference?

Comment: Consider using a `std::unordered_map<int/* flight number*/, std::unique_ptr<Flight>>` instead. A deletion is then trivial, amongst other things such as memory management.

Comment: Show the Flight class. Is there FlightNumber member variable in it?

Comment: Ought not to be: a flight number is more of a property of a *collection*.

Comment: @YeoMengTat What is it you are trying to do with this function? Would you just like to know if the `Agent` has a flight with a specific flight number? I don't see the sense in deleting.

Comment: @YeoMengTat I can't help you without seeing more of your code (at least your Flight class/struct). I assume that your Flight type is composed of at least an int member variable that is used to represent a flight number. So what you would want to do is read the flight number from the user, construct an instance of type Flight (passing the read flight number into it), then using that instance in your delete method.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman no, the agent is the class which holds a list of flight objects. So, the agent is responsible for deleting flight objects. Now my question is there any possible way for me to retrieve an element from Flight class to be compared to the input in the main so I could delete the element in that flight class.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi yes that is what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can add(if not present) a getter in Flight class

```
class Flight{
int FlightNumber;

public:

int getflightNumber(){ return flightNumber;}
};
```

and go as following:-

```
void Agent::delete(int flightNumber)
{
    vector<Flight*>::iterator ptr;
    for(ptr=flightList.begin();ptr!=flightList.end();ptr++)
    {
        if(((*Ptr)->getflightNumber() == flightNumber)
        {
            flightList.erase(ptr);
            break;
        }
    }
    if ((fPtr) == listFlight.end())
    {
        cout<<"Flight not found"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have did this previously, however ptr is unable to request for member getFlight ... which is of pointer type (maybe you meant to use '->'

Comment: the method int getflightNumber(); should be public. May be you missed that.

Comment: I have declared it, but still the same result shows.

Answer (score 1):

*Since the code here isn't fully functional, it's hard to give you good advice.*

First, your error happens because you call (what seems to be) the member function, `void Agent::delete(Flight *obj)`, with a variable of type `int` instead of type `Flight`. The compiler is not able to interpret your `Flight` object as an `int`, so it throws an error.

Secondly, you want to know how to retrieve attributes from an object. I will advise you to have a look to **accessors** and **mutators**.

If you want to retrieve information hold in your `Flight` object, you should expose member functions allowing that.

```
// in your header file
class Flight
{
private:
    int flight_number;

public:
    // retrieve flight number value
    int get_flight_number(void) const;
    // allow to set the flight number value
    void set_flight_number(int new_flight_number);
    // some other member functions
}

// in your source file
int Flight::get_flight_number(void) const
{
   return this->flight_number;
}

void Flight::set_flight_number(int new_flight_number)
{
    // let's do some verification (do whatever you want)
    if (new_flight_number > 0)
    {
         this->flight_number = new_flight_number;
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to set and access your `flight_number` by writing, for example :

```
void test_function(Flight *f)
{
    if (f->get_flight_number() == 42)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

int main()
{
    Flight *my_f = new Flight();
    my_f->set_flight_number = 4242;
    my_test_function(my_f);
}
```

Now, you have enough information to get going.

**NOTES :**

You heavily use pointers. Modern C++ strongly tends to **not**! Try to use references or move operation. You can consult this pages for info:

- [cpp-reference - references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)
- [cpp-reference - move semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

It's a bit hardcore for beginner though. The web is full of great article. about it

Answer (score 0):

You original error is in your main method. You need to change it so that instead of passing the flight number to your `delete` method, you create an instance of your `Flight` class.

```
int main() { // you are also missing parenthesis
      Agent agent1;
      int flightNumber;
      cout<<"Enter the number of the flight: "<<flush; // I don't know what flush is but maybe you meant std::endl
      cin>>flightNumber;
      Flight flight(flightNumber);
      agent1.delete(&flight); // delete takes a Flight* not an int
}
```

This requires that your Flight class have an appropriate constructor.

```
class Flight
{
public:
    Flight(int flightNumber)
        : flightNumber_(flightNumber)
    {}

private:
    int flightNumber_;
};
```

Then in your `delete` method you search your vector for the `Flight` instance that has the same `flightNumber_` as the `Flight` you want to remove from your vector. This will require your `Flight` class to have some way of returning it's `flightNumber_` member variable.

This is definitely NOT the best way to do this and is far from being in accordance with modern C++ standards but it should get you going.